# Mongo Database Fixing Names after Mongoose Index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I had a very weird issue with the way Mongoose interacted with my Node and Mongo database.

I was using express to create a basic get api route to fetch some data from my mongodb.

I had a database called test and it had a collection call "billings"

so the schema and route was pretty basic

> apiRouter.route('/billing/')

```
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Billing.find(function(err, billings) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            // return the bills
            res.json(billings);
        });
    });
```

Where "Billing" was my mongoose schema. that simply had 1 object {test: string}

This worked fine, I got a response with all the items in my mongo db called "billings" which is only one item {test: "success"}

Next I created a collection called "historys"

I setup the exact same setup as my billings.

> apiRouter.route('/historys/')

```
    // get all the history
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Historys.find(function(err, historys) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            // return the history
            res.json(historys);
        });
    });
```

where again "Historys" was my mongoose schema. This schema was identical in setup to my billings since I didnt have any real data, the fields were the same, i just had it with a test field so the json object returned from both billings and historys should have been

> { test: "success" }

However, this time I didnt get any data back, I just got an empty object

> [].

I went through my code multiple times to make sure maybe a capital got lost, or a comma somewhere etc, but the code was identical. the setup and formatting in my mongodb was identical. I went into robomongo and viewed the database and everything was named correctly.

Except, I had 2 new collections now.

My original : "Historys" AND a brand new collection "Histories"

Once i fixed my api route to go look at Histories instead of Historys, I was able to get the test data successfully. I still however cannot pull data from Historys, its like it doesnt exist yet there it was in my robomongo console when I refreshed.

I searched all my code for any mention of histories and got 0 results. Where did the system know to fix the grammar on my collection?

Comment: How did you insert the `{ test: "success" }` into the `Historys` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option.

So, when you did, in your schema definition, this:

```
mongoose.model('Historys', YourSchema);
```

, mongoose created the `Histories` collection.

When you do:

```
db.historys.insert({ test: "success" })
```

through `mongodb` console, if the `historys` collection doesn't exist, it'll be created. That's why you have the two collections in your db. Like the docs said, if you don't want `mongoose` to create a collection with a pluralized name based on your model, just specify the name you want.